# images in gridview from lazyloading are mixing places on scroll

Tags: android

In my application, i am lazy loading images from URLs into a gridview.
When i scroll my gridView, the images change their positions.
How is this possible ?
I am new to android so please can anyone helpme ?

This is my list adapter code :

```
import android.app.Activity; import android.content.Context; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.View.OnClickListener; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.BaseAdapter; import android.widget.ImageView;   public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] mStrings;
    private Context mContext;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Context context, Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        mStrings=d;
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {    
        View grid;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(mStrings[position], imageView);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        grid.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }


    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{          
        private int mPosition;

       OnItemClickListener(int position){
             mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MainActivityLoading sct = (MainActivityLoading)activity;
            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }              
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using view holder pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(mStrings[position], imageView);


    //Use gridView's setOnItemClickListener
    //convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

The point here is that you must set the values once you get a not-null `convertView`.

Since you are setting the ImageView's url in the if block:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(mStrings[position], imageView);
```

If the `convertView` is not null i.e If the **GridView** starts recycling the views, you will get the old `convertView` which is out of the screen and **whose image url is different**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your gridview recycles views for faster display. You must set a tag to your imageView and check that the image url corresponds to the same your are loading in your lazy implementation. It happens because the image download happens in an asynctask, and probably by the time the image gets downloaded the view is already recycled.

Hope it helps.